# How do you void a shipment in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

How do you void a shipment in Magento 2? I didn't see an option for this in the Admin GUI.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality for this does not yet exist:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1584